# Symfony3 and Apache

Tags: php, apache, symfony, symfony-3.1

I was testing two configurations of `apache2` `*.conf` file and in first example everything ok, but i can't get public pictures in web folder like favicon or any other images in web folder.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName project2
        DocumentRoot /var/www/project2/web/app_dev.php
<Directory /var/www/project2/web>
AllowOverride All
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from All
</Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

In second case i cahnge `DocumentRoot /var/www/project2/web/app_dev.php` to `DocumentRoot /var/www/project2/web` and i can get pictures, but controller returns internal server error when i'm using `{ff}` some variables in route

```
/**
 * 
 * @Route("/{ff}",name="home")
 */
```

This code `@Route("/{ff}",name="home")` don't work if i use [recommended](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html) syntax in apache configuration. How to configure apache?

Answer (score 1):

The official Symfony documentation features a detailed article on how to set up Apache for Symfony: http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Also, be sure to enable `mod_rewrite` in your `httpd.conf`.

Comment: @fonjeekay If this answer helped you to resolve the issue please accept it.